# Writing to 2 SD cards at the same time

Tags: sd-card, tee, pv

I would like to [write an image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522138/replicating-an-sd-card?noredirect=1#comment965990_522138) at two SD cards at the same time.  I envision at least two concurrent writing scenarios:

1. Is it possible to write the image with a `tee` or similar bifurcating mechanism?
2. Is it possible to execute the cat or pv command from two different BASH shells?

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'pv sdcard.image >/dev/sdb'
   sudo sh -c 'pv sdcard.image >/dev/mmcblk0'

   sudo sh -c 'cat sdcard.image >/dev/sdb'
   sudo sh -c 'cat sdcard.image >/dev/mmcblk0'
   ```

I can foresee a problem in that if the two targets can be written at different rates, then it may be necessary to throttle write speed down so as to not overload the slower writer.
The image is large: the ability to burn multiple targets is a significant advantage.

Comment: What do you mean with `at the same time`? Do you just want ONE command to write both devices with the image?

Comment: @matsib.dev  Good question: Yes, the goal is to burn  two SD cards concurrently instead of one.  It would be preferable that a the image file is read once and burns two cards with a one-liner from the command line.

Comment: @gatorback Ok, take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to write the image with a tee or similar bifurcating mechanism?

```
sudo tee /dev/sdb /dev/mmcblk0 < sdcard.image > /dev/null
```

Comment: Please add a small narrative to walk the reader through the thought process.  It would be nice if the image file was not returned to the console and progress \ status was displayed.  Thank you

Comment: The concern that when the very large image is displayed on the console the process would unnecessarily slow

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to execute the cat command from two different BASH shells?

Which `cat` command?

---

If you just want to achieve the same result as here:

> `sudo sh -c 'pv sdcard.image >/dev/sdb'`
>
> `sudo sh -c 'pv sdcard.image >/dev/mmcblk0'`

but with one Enter hit, why not simply combine the commands like this?:

`sudo sh -c 'pv sdcard.image /dev/sdb && pv sdcard.image /dev/mmcblk0'`

Is it because you don't want to read the file twice?

(with `&&`, the second commands it's executed, only if the first command succeed; if you want to execute the second command anyways, you can change the `&&` for a `;`)

---

To read the file from the filesystem only once, you can do this:

`cat sdcard.image | tee /dev/sdb > /dev/mmcblk0`

Here, your are taking advantage of `tee` default behavior:
what `tee` sends to a file, you send it to one of your device targets, giving that device as a file argument of the `tee` command, and what `tee` sends to *stdout*, you redirect it to your other device target.

---

Or, reading the image twice, but doing **both writes at the same time**, in *parallel*, with `parallel`:

```
parallel 'cat sdcard.image >' ::: /dev/{sdb,mmcblk0}
```

Note: bare in mind that this `parallel`, is the `GNU parallel`, and not the `moreutils parallel`

Answer (score -2):

This is bare minimum shell script for concurrent copying. If any errors this will throw them to STDERR.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Image file ${1}"
echo "1st SD Card Path ${2}"
echo "2nd SD Card Path ${3}"

dd if=${1} of=${2}&
dd if=${1} of=${3}
```

Usage `sh script.sh image_file first_card_path second_card_path`

Comment: This would read the image file twice. (Also, please quote your variables!)

Comment: Please give `dd` a decent buffer size. Writing 512 byte blocks to a 4K-block SD card is wrong. (You may find `cat` is faster anyway.)