# Replicating an SD card to a larger SD card

Tags: partition, raspberry-pi, sd-card, cloning

In a previous posting, the [Replication of a Raspberry pi SD Card](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522514/182280) is performed on an identical target SD card.  If the goal is to replicate to a larger SD card with the same procedure:

If the source device is `/dev/sdb` and the target device is `/dev/sdc`. To replicate the SD card, run the following command as root:

```
sudo cat /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc
```

The SD card would need to be modified to extend the partition to utilize the incremental space on the larger SD card.

1. What are the options to extend the partition and is there a best-practice?
2. Is there a better (single step) command than `cat` that replicates the smaller SD card to the larger device and ensures the maximum size partition?

Is there a "best practice" or context-driven decision making process ("It depends on ....")?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the raspberry pi boot scripts might do this for you already, or they used to. Here: somebody *doesn't want* it: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56621/temporarily-disable-expand-filesystem-during-first-boot

Comment: @A.B  After burning a Raspbian "disk", I have used raspbian's [`raspi-config`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md) utility to resize the disk and enable Raspbian to utilize the entirety of the SD-Card.   In this exercise, raspi-config is not available because a different distro is replicated.  Maybe this functionality common to all rPi Distros?

Comment: @JeffSchaller:  I noticed that the `cat` tag was removed.  Please help me understand the why, so that I can make better decisions when choosing tags

Comment: It seemed to me that the `cat` command was incidental to the question -- that it was either a predecessor or successor to a re-partioning step or was to be replaced by a "better (single step) command". Feel free to re-add it if you think it's central to the question. @gatorback

Answer (score 1):

If you're replicating it on a PC and not the pi you can probably use gparted to copy and then enlarge the partition.