# Can the zerofree process be performed on SD-Card image file?

Tags: sd-card, disk-image

[image]

Ubuntu 16.04: A 64GB SD-Card image was created with the command:

```
date; sudo sh -c 'pv /dev/mmcblk0 >rpi4_Ubuntu18.1_64GB.image'; date
```

The rasbperry pi SD-Card is outfitted with Ubuntu 18.1

Can a Ubuntu 16.04 laptop:

- mount the .image file?
- run zerofree on the mounting point of the .image file?
- unmount the .image file?

I am aware that it is possible to restore the image file to the SD-card and process the card with [zerofree](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/Zerofree_Write_Zeros_to_Free_Space_-_Raspberry_Pi) and snapping the image again.  It would be nice to be able to process several .image files without restoring them to the SD card.

## UPDATE: Test results

Image successfully mounted to /dev/loop9p2:

```
$ sudo losetup -P /dev/loop9 rpi4_Ubuntu18.1_64GB.image
$ ls -l /dev/loop9*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   7, 9 Feb  2 19:12 /dev/loop9
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 Feb  2 19:12 /dev/loop9p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1 Feb  2 19:12 /dev/loop9p2
```

zerofree failure:

```
$ zerofree -v /dev/loop9p2
zerofree: failed to open filesystem /dev/loop9p2
```

zerofree required `sudo`:

```
$ sudo zerofree -v /dev/loop9p2
14346339/14348998/15073019
```

- 14346339 number of nonzero blocks encountered
- 14348998 number of free blocks within the filesystem
- 15073019 total number of blocks within the filesystem

Bonus: reduce image size with script [pishrink](https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink)

Comment: What OS and filesystem are you using?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli  Good question: I have updated the OP to indicate that both the SD card and the workstation are Ubuntu 18.1 and 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zerofree` operates on a compatible filesystem, no matter what is the underlying storage medium. The version of `zerofree` on my Debian 10 system supports `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4` filesystems, so if the filesystem used on the SD-card is one of those, the answer would be **yes**.

But it looks like you have imaged the whole card, which may have more than one partition on it. If that's the case, you won't be able to just "mount the image file", as the mount command handles one filesystem at a time only. And on a whole-disk image, the partition table usually occupies some space at the beginning of the disk, so you might not be able to even access the first filesystem on the image by attempting to mount the whole-card image directly.

If your system has a `losetup` command that supports the `-P` option, you could do a `losetup -P /dev/loop0 rpi4_Ubuntu18.1_64GB.image`, which would give you devices like `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2` etc. - one for each partition in the image file. You could then mount each of those partition devices and run `zerofree` on them, then unmount and `losetup -d /dev/loop0` to detach the loop device.

If your `losetup` command won't support the `-P` option, there is an alternative: the `kpartx` tool (sometimes packaged separately, sometimes as part of the `device-mapper-multipath` tools) can create mappings for individual partitions. In this case, you would first use `losetup /dev/loop0 rpi4_Ubuntu18.1_64GB.image` to attach the loop device, then `kpartx -a /dev/loop` to create mapping devices for each partition detected on it. The partition devices will be named a bit differently in this case: they will be `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` etc. The mounting and `zerofree` procedure would be otherwise the same, but the clean-up after you've unmounted the filesystem would also require two steps: first `kpartx -d /dev/loop0` to delete the partition mapping devices, then `losetup -d /dev/loop0` to delete the main loop device.

Comment: `losetup` mapped the ext4 partition  to `/dev/loop9p2`,  which was mounted to /mnt/image.  Why does `zerofree -v /dev/loop9p2` return `zerofree: filesystem /dev/loop9p2 is mounted rw?`   What message is returned when zerofree is successful?

Comment: From the man page of `zerofree`: "filesystem has to be unmounted or mounted read-only for zerofree to work. It will exit with an error message if the filesystem is  mounted writable." I actually thought you had some other reason to mount the filesystem beyond running `zerofree`. So unless you have some specific reason to mount the filesystem, don't mount it before running `zerofree` on it.

Comment: Please consider commenting on test results at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: Note that the `/dev/loop9p2` device is accessible by `root` or members of the group `disk` only, and by default a regular user is neither. So you'll need to use `sudo` with the `zerofree` command.