# OSX: how to mount raspberry pi image file?

Tags: raspberry-pi, loop-device, macos

## BACKGROUND

The [loop device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565450/182280) is available in Ubuntu and is the first step to processing the rPi image with `zerofree`.

The goal is to reproduce the **UBUNTU example** with OSX High-Sierra:

## UBUNTU example

Raspberry Pi image successfully mounted to /dev/loop9p2:

```
$ sudo losetup -P /dev/loop9 rpi4_Ubuntu18.1_64GB.image
$ ls -l /dev/loop9*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   7, 9 Feb  2 19:12 /dev/loop9
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 Feb  2 19:12 /dev/loop9p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1 Feb  2 19:12 /dev/loop9p2
```

zerofree required `sudo`:

```
$ sudo zerofree -v /dev/loop9p2
14346339/14348998/15073019
```

- 14346339 number of nonzero blocks encountered
- 14348998 number of free blocks within the filesystem
- 15073019 total number of blocks within the filesystem

## QUESTIONS

1. Does OSX have an equivalent for a loop device?
2. What are the OSX equivalents for `losetup` (brew commands are an option)?

I will save zerofree equivalent questions for a future posting

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9284/does-mac-have-something-similar-to-a-linux-loop-device-alternative-to-losetup/9288

Comment: Add a tag wiki and excerpt to the new tag you created, please: https://unix.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/5548