# Replicating SD card: hangs at 99%

Tags: sd-card, pv

The goal is to [replicate an SD card](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522138/replicating-an-sd-card).

Despite successfully replicating the SD card a few years ago, a recent attempt hangs at 99%, despite attempts from 2 different PCs.

```shellsession
user@JUPITER Desktop$ date; sudo sh -c 'pv sdcard.image >/dev/disk5'; date
Fri Mar 17 00:42:51 EDT 2023
 119GiB 6:10:50 [0.00 B/s] [==========================================> ] 99% ETA 0:00:18
```

Is there any way to measure the SD card to determine if it somehow too small to accommodate the image?

`diskutil list` returned:

```
/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *127.9 GB   disk5
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 NO NAME                 254.8 MB   disk5s1
   2:                      Linux                         127.7 GB   disk5s2
```

The command:

```bash
ls -l sdcard.image
```

returns:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  128043712512 Oct 29  2021 sdcard.image
```

Comment: How long did you wait?  Maybe it was just buffering it out.  PV knows what it wrote, but it doesn't know how much is in the buffers being flushed to the disk.  What operating system is this?

Comment: I let it run overnight 7+ hours.  MacOS UNIX